# Change "prefs" to "preferences"

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, preferences

We use long words like "reputation", so is there a good reason to abbreviate "preferences" to "prefs"?

#### EDIT:

I'm not bothered by it, it just seems wrong.

Comment: Jeff is doing it to seem 'edgy'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Historical fact: it originally *was* "preferences". With the addition of several new tabs in the user profile, I think it was necessary to shorten it. I think that changing it back confers no benefit and can be detrimental as that space can be used for additional, future tabs.

Answer (score 1):

We can also argue to change reputation to rep and favourites to fav. I have no problem with it being called prefs.

Comment: At least if we changed "reputation" to "rep" we might stop seeing "reps" used as an abbreviation...

Answer (score 0):

Prefs is a much more common short form and everyone *should* understand what it means. The meaning of rep may not be well understood to some users, and it's better to have it clear from the start. If you notice statistics is also shortened to stats, because again its meaning is more or less global. I have no idea if this is the real reasoning behind this, but it seems more than valid to me.